# Tooltip for List items

Tags: html, font-awesome-5

```
<li class="list-inline-item">
   <i class="fab fa-mailchimp"></i>
</li>
```

I have this font awesome icon that I would like to add. I need a tooltip to display some text upon hover. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<li title="<insert hover text here>" class="list-inline-item">
<i class="fab fa-mailchimp"></i>
</li>
```